# Need to trigger a job as and when quartz scheduler starts

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Quartz scheduler wont trigger my job when I start it. My job is scheduled for every hour. but after starting my scheduler, My first job is trigged after an hour. I'm new to quartz. below is my quartz launch code

```
    JobKey feedWSClient = new JobKey("feedWSClient", "feed-validator");
    JobDetail feedWSJob = JobBuilder.newJob(this).withIdentity(feedWSClient).build();
    Trigger feedWSCListenerTrigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
       .withIdentity("feedWSCListenerTrigger","feed-validator")
       .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0/59 * * * ?")).build();       

    Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
    scheduler.scheduleJob(feedWSJob,feedWSCListenerTrigger);
    scheduler.start();
```

Comment: Your cron string means "Do on the zeroth minute of midnight and every 59 hours" (which doesn't make sense). I think you should change your second field to `*`.

Comment: Thank you, but the given corn expression executes every hour as it should be and there is no problem in it, just it wont start when start the scheduler. Do you have any idea?

Comment: It is incorrect (Should be `0 * * * * ?`), but perhaps it's just ignoring your second field because it doesn't make sense. In any case, it specifically says to start at the zeroth minute of each hour. It has no connection to when you start the scheduler, only to the clock.

Comment: idk, it actually works for me.for instance if i change it 0 0/1 * * * ? the job is triggered after every minute. I just tried it. may be I will take another look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code worked for me. 
http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/

```
scheduler.start();
scheduler.triggerJob(feedWSClient);
```

Need to call the above statement after starting the scheduler with jobkey.